# SQL Dependency query text

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have noticed that on one of my old asp.net applications (running on Azure now and now using SQL azure database) that I get the SQL txt for all queries run against the database contained within the SQL Dependency telemetry. This is great and has helped me target queries to optomise.

I have a newer app (running in a raskspace data centre) that is also showing SQL telemetry, but the query txt is missing.

Do I need to be running within Azure for the query txt to be included, or is there something that I can do to enable this feature?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken here, but I remember that when one uses AI Status Monitor to collect dependencies - the command text is collected, when one uses .NET 4.5.2 and no AI Status Monitor - then the embedded .NET collection does not extract the command text.

This might be your case if the old asp.net app you mention is .NET 4.0 and AI Status Monitor is installed on that box, while the new app is 4.5+ without the AI Status Monitor on the box (which might be expected for the data center).